# Discord.js embed bot message answer

Tags: discord.js, bots

I want to make a simple embed bot answer. Here's the code:

```
    client.on("message", function(msg){
    if (message.content === 'help') {
    msg.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("test")
            .setDescription(")
            .setColor("#148837")
            .setAuthor('steve')
            .setURL("")
            .setThumbnail("")
        )}
   
});
```

But yeah as you can see it won't work. Anyone got an solution?
It's just a simple answer to a message that contains "help".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change the `if(message.content === 'help')` to `if(msg.content === 'help')`, because your function gets the parameter with name `msg` not `message`.